# 3D plot of the spatial path of velocity/space stochastic differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, probability-or-statistics

I define the following 6 dimensional stochastic (Ito) process- in velocity v/position x. I can plot x1 as a function of t- see script below which has been corrected by Daniel. My goal is however to plot the path `[x1[t],x2[t],x3[t]]` in 3D. Any help?

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code, e.g. `[DifferentialD]` should be replaced by `d` and `[Distributed]` should be replaced by `\[Distributed]`.

Comment: corrected below

Answer (score 1):

I corrected Differential and Distributed:

```
proc = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]x1[t] == 
    v1[t] \[DifferentialD]t, \[DifferentialD]x2[t] == 
    v2[t] \[DifferentialD]t, \[DifferentialD]x3[t] == 
    v3[t] \[DifferentialD]t, \[DifferentialD]v1[t] == -0.1*
      v1[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]n1[
       t], \[DifferentialD]v2[t] == -0.1*
      v2[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]n2[
       t], \[DifferentialD]v3[t] == -0.1*
      v3[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]n3[t]}, 
  x1[t], {{x1, x2, x3, v1, v2, v3}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, 
  t, {n1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
   n2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
   n3 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]}] 
sol = RandomFunction[proc, {0., 100, 0.1}, 50, 
  Method -> "StochasticRungeKutta"]; ListLinePlot[sol]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

If you want to plot the 3 first data-path as 3D path you may do this by:

```
ListLinePlot3D[sol["Values", 1 ;; 3] // Transpose]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I would like to plot (x1,x2,x3) as a function of time in 3D? any clue?

Comment: Think of `ListPointPlot3D`.

Comment: Can you give me a script that would do? thanks

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. I added a 3D path out of the first 3 paths from "sol" to my answer

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I have 1 path of x1,x2,x3 as function of time. That's the meaning of 1;;3 I guess. 4;;6 would give the velocity path. So what is the meaning of transpose? what if I want 30 paths?

Comment: I also would like to plot (x1,x2), the 2D path on a 2D plot. ListLinePlot2D[sol["Values", 1;;2]//Transpose] ?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Ito process to output the three x values, {x1[t],x2[t],x3[t]} instead of just x1[t]:

```
proc = ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]x1[t] == 
v1[t] \[DifferentialD]t, \[DifferentialD]x2[t] == 
v2[t] \[DifferentialD]t, \[DifferentialD]x3[t] == 
v3[t] \[DifferentialD]t, \[DifferentialD]v1[t] == -0.1*
  v1[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]n1[
   t], \[DifferentialD]v2[t] == -0.1*
  v2[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]n2[
   t], \[DifferentialD]v3[t] == -0.1*
  v3[t] \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]n3[t]}, 
{x1[t], x2[t],x3[t]}, 
{{x1, x2, x3, v1, v2, v3}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, 
t, {n1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
    n2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[], 
    n3 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]}]
```

After solving this version of the Ito process, extract and plot the paths:

```
Graphics3D[Line[sol["ValueList"]]]
```

If you want to style each path, you can extract them individually from the solution, e.g, with sol["Values",p] for the {x1,x2,x3} values for path p.

[image: paths from Ito stochastic process]

Comment: Thank Tad. That is starting to help. Is there a way to have each sample path in different color? I need these (or variations around the same problem) for an article I am preparing for The Astrophysical Journal.

Comment: @NicolasBian For different colors `Table[sol["Values", i], {i, 1, 50}] // 
 ListPointPlot3D[#, AspectRatio -> 1] &`